# Mimicking a native iPad tab bar icon look and feel in a WebApp

Tags: web-applications

Does anyone know a good way (or source) to get the look and feel of a native iPad tab bar icon? I know about position:fixed for the bar itself. I'm asking about the icon apearance.

In particular:

- What is the size for the graphic image for each icon?
- What is the font size of the text under the graphic image?
- What are the limits of the combined graphic + text for each icon?
- What is the best way to mimic the selected/unselected looks?

Answer (score 0):

You will find a tremendous amount of information on this from Apple itself. Especially in their Human Interface Guidelines.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Principles/Principles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH5-SW6

Apple also has their veto on interfaces which fail to meet specific requirements to be allowed on the app store, such as icons cannot be smaller than 42 pixels.

You can find more information on the same page as above, but the part discussing the iOS UI elements.

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html

You may also find some inspiration (not necessarily answers per se) by googling for iPad interface or guy psd's